# Why doesn't Windows 7 boot with BootCamp?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, efi

I installed Windows 7 (from MSDNAA) with BootCamp on my MBP (late 2008). After using the BootCamp utility on OSX I restarted the computer and the installation of Win7 began. This first time, there were no partitions to choose as destination. After a restart, I could install Win7 on the Bootcamp partition.

Now every time I try to start Win7, a black screen appears and nothing happens anymore. I tried it with hitting "alt" and choosing windows from the boot menu, I tried rEFIt and choosing windows, I tried selecting windows from the startup disk menu in OSX... I installed Windows at least 5 times, but always get the same problem. The strange thing is: the Windows partition appears in OSX and I can browse the Windows folder, the program files, ...

Any idea what I can try now?

Comment: Are you running 10.6 and the Boot Camp 3.1 Update?

Comment: Is it a 32 or a 64bit Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I had weird issues trying to get boot camp to load/run windows.  Tried everything and it turned out to be the RAM.  I put back in the factory RAM, installed boot camp, then put back my newer RAM after it worked.

It may not be your issue, but thought I would try.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a display driver related issue, try booting windows into Safe Mode by pressing the F8 key as soon as Windows starts.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a CD/DVD in drive when trying to boot to Windows? The BIOS -emulator will try to boot from CD's/DVD's and external USB drives when booting to windows. Just try and remove all external devices (also USB mice etc) and discs and see if it works.

I haven't found a way to alter the boot preferences for the emulated BIOS yet.

Answer (score 0):

It will work in OS Lion. It was reported that the developer build of OS Lion will ONLY work with Windows 7 in Boot Camp.

I know it doesn't solve the issue right now, but it's good to know about.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this multiple times, I had to connect an external display because it was some driver issue with the iMac's display, and update the drivers within windows to resolve.

Good thing I had a projector handy.